# Cross validation - feature information outside the fold

Tags: cross-validation

i am building a model that predicts likelihood of the presence of an infectious disease across 10000 villages. There is spatial dimension - each villages is surrounded by e.g. 8 other villages, and presence of disease in a nearby village increased the likelihood of disease in the village in question.

I created a feature that sums the number of cases in the 8 nearby villages. However - initially - i created this value on the entire dataset. With regards to e.g. 10 fold cross validation - is this "wrong"? Am i bringing in information from "outside the fold" and hence bias the performance? Should i run the feature creation within each fold, even those some of the nearby villages will be outside the fold? (also - computationally this might become very heavy...)

Thoughts welcome - much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this will potentially introduce a bias in the performance estimates, so I would recommend repeating the calculation independently in each fold.  It is best to regard cross-validation as a means of estimating the performance of a *method* of generating a model, rather than of the model itself, so you need to perform *every* step of that method independently in each fold in order to get an (approximately) unbiased performance estimate.